# Make an anchor acts as a submit button. Not just using click event

Tags: jquery

Something like this will works only when user clicks the anchor. But a form also is submitted when user push [enter] key inside the form. How could I have the same functionality using just an anchor?

```
    $('a.submit').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Thanks.-

EDIT (with solution):

This combination works (at least) in FF and chrome! either clicking the anchor with class *submit* or pressing [enter].

```
    $('#my_form a.submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
}); 

$('#my_form').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13)
        return;
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Coudl you clarify what you are after? Are you trying to get code to run when a form is submitted with the enter key? If so you might like to look at onsubmit even handlers. Otherwise I am not sure what you're after...

Comment: @chris No, I want submit the form with this anchor. AFAIK it is needed a submit or image button to trigger the submit action (either clicking or pushing [enter]).

Comment: Ah yes. Pressing enter may require there to be a button. I've a feeling that it doesn't require the button to be visible though so try adding a dummy one and setting its visibility to false or display to none using CSS and see if that helps at all. There may well be better ways to do this though...

Comment: @chris I'll try that. I was trying bind a listener of [enter] key on a keydown event over the form.

Comment: @chris works in FF but not in chrome, besides in both interferes with the anchor click event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several test this is perfectly working:

```
$('#my_form a.submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
}); 

$('#my_form').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) // Enter or Return keystroke
        return;
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to prevent the click event from firing the anchor:

```
$('a.submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```